# strange curve that NyquistPlot gives for delayed first-order system

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I've got a strange result from `NyquistPlot` for a delayed first-order system $\frac{e^{-i\pi /2}}{s + 1}$, using the mathematica code:

```
NyquistPlot[TransferFunctionModel[E^(-\[ImaginaryJ] \[Pi]/2)/(s + 1), s]
    ,AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> Full,PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

this is the result plot with a strange “drifting” “upside down” portion of arc:
[image: NyquistPlot result for a delayed first-order system]

which is expected to be a complete normal circle right focus at (0,-0.5) like this (I drawed it using `Graphics` and `Circle` but not `NyquistPlot`!):
[image: expected NyquistPlot result for a delayed first-order system]

Addionally, for simple first-order system  **without time-delay** $\frac{1}{s + 1}$, the plot result is just right  circle focus at (0.5,0):

```
 NyquistPlot[TransferFunctionModel[1/(s + 1), s], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
      PlotRange -> Full, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

I check existed questions here by keyword `NyquestPlot` but nothing relevant.

Even is there some limitation in mathematica?
or what's wrong in my code or in my expectation? Is there something I miss when using `NyquistPlot`?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think this is a nonphysical system rather than a time-delay system. (The output response is imaginary and not delayed.)

I don't think `NyquistPlot` was designed to automatically handle such systems. As a workaround you can do:

```
NyquistPlot[TransferFunctionModel[E^(-I \[Pi]/2)/(s + 1), s], {-501, 500}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]